# No puedo usar la función GetAdaptersAddresses()

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un código en C y hay una parte que necesito recoger una lista de las macs del dispositivo.
El caso esta en que importo la librería iphlpapi.h y intento usar la función per no aparece.
No se si ese header hay que descargarlo en algún sitio externo pero he visto en mi PC y si está el archivo.
Realmente no se que información proporcionar-hos ya que es simplemente eso... como mucho, instalé MSYS2 que de ahí es donde vienen los headers usados.

Comment: Estás en Visual Studio, usando el compilador de Microsoft? Asegúrate de tener instalado el SDK de Windows 10.